Customize minipage to support spaces below it
I'm trying to create a custom minipage environment that allows spaces above and below it. I manage to control the spaces above using the @minipage shitch, but I can't find the modification to achieve the spaces below it.
I have used coffins just to be able to visualize the box that is in the minipage environment, and apparently the space above it with my modifications is "almost correct", the idea behind this is to be able to use this environment to align figures on top [t] with a nested enumerate environment, so I want to preserve the topsep value of this above and below the environment.
The code (MWE) that I have is the following:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,enumitem}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\coffin_new:N \l_myminipage_one_coffin
\NewDocumentEnvironment { myminipage } { m }
  {
    %\fboxsep0pt
    \vcoffin_set:Nnw \l_myminipage_one_coffin { #1 } %% only for debug
      \noindent
      \minipage[t]{#1}
        \legacy_if_gset_false:n { @minipage }
        \vspace { 0pt }
  }
  {
      \endminipage
    \vcoffin_set_end:
    %\fbox{\coffin_display_handles:Nn \l_myminipage_one_coffin { red }} %% only for debug
    \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l_myminipage_one_coffin {l}{H}{0pt}{0pt} %% only for debug
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% The environment starts
\begin{enumerate}[partopsep=0pt,topsep=0pt, parsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt]

\item Now a standard nested enumeration% with \verb+topsep=10pt, itemsep=0pt+.

  \begin{enumerate}[left=0pt,topsep=10pt,itemsep=0pt]
    \item A The text separation above this line is correct \verb+topsep=10pt+.
    \item B The text separation below this line is correct \verb+topsep=10pt+.
  \end{enumerate}

\item The text separation above this line is correct%% \verb+topsep=10pt+.

  \begin{myminipage}{0.7\textwidth}
    \begin{enumerate}[left=0pt,topsep=10pt,itemsep=0pt]
      \item C The text separation above is correct?
      \item D The text separation below incorrect.
     \end{enumerate}
  \end{myminipage}\hfill
  \begin{myminipage}{0.2\textwidth}
    \par\addvspace{ 10pt } % or \vspace{10pt} here know the value off space
    \centering
    \fbox{Image here}
  \end{myminipage}
  %%\par\addvspace{20pt} % manual add topsep fix the problem but only if partopsep=0pt

\item E The text separation above incorrect% NOT equal to \verb+topsep=10pt+.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}


I have checked ltboxes from the official source2e documentation and several answers here in the forum, but I can't manage to fit them to my requirement, so the question is:
Which macro in the minipage definition should be modified to support spaces below? (preferably using expl3)
As a secondary question, what parameter is making the top space a little more than topsep=10pt in myminipage? ...in theory it should look the same as the nested enumerate environment before it.

The definition of \end{minipage} is:
\def\endminipage{%
    \par
    \unskip
    \ifvoid\@mpfootins\else
      \vskip\skip\@mpfootins
      \normalcolor
      \footnoterule
      \unvbox\@mpfootins
    \fi
    \@minipagefalse   %% added 24 May 89
  \color@endgroup
  \egroup
  \expandafter\@iiiparbox\@mpargs{\unvbox\@tempboxa}}

It's the \unskip here that's removing any space at the end, so you somehow need to protect the final space from \unskip. There are essentially infinite solutions to this problem, although they fall into 3 main categories:

Use an “empty” vertical mode command:

\special{}

\vspace*{0pt}

\hrule height 0pt width 0pt depth 0pt\relax

\kern 0pt


All of these commands insert a non-skip into the vertical list to hide the final skip from \unskip, and all of these commands produce no visible output.

Insert a skip that can be safely removed:

\vskip 0pt

\vspace{0pt}

\skip_vertical:n { 0pt }


If you insert a \vskip at the very end, then \unskip will remove that instead of the original bottom skip.

Replace the final skip with something else:

\dimen0\lastskip\unskip\kern\dimen0

\unskip doesn't remove kerns, so we can replace the final skip with a kern of the exact same height.



Full example:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,enumitem}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\coffin_new:N \l_myminipage_one_coffin
\NewDocumentEnvironment { myminipage } { m }
  {
    %\fboxsep0pt
    \vcoffin_set:Nnw \l_myminipage_one_coffin { #1 } %% only for debug
      \noindent
      \minipage[t]{#1}
        \legacy_if_gset_false:n { @minipage }
        \vspace { 0pt }
  }
  {
      %%% Any of the following lines will fix the problem
      % \special{}
      % \vspace*{0pt}
      % \hrule height 0pt width 0pt depth 0pt\relax
      % \kern 0pt
      % \vskip 0pt
      % \vspace{0pt}
      % \dimen0\lastskip\unskip\kern\dimen0
      %%% End
      \endminipage
    \vcoffin_set_end:
    %\fbox{\coffin_display_handles:Nn \l_myminipage_one_coffin { red }} %% only for debug
    \coffin_typeset:Nnnnn \l_myminipage_one_coffin {l}{H}{0pt}{0pt} %% only for debug
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% The environment starts
\begin{enumerate}[partopsep=0pt,topsep=0pt, parsep=0pt, itemsep=0pt]

\item Now a standard nested enumeration% with \verb+topsep=10pt, itemsep=0pt+.

  \begin{enumerate}[left=0pt,topsep=10pt,itemsep=0pt]
    \item A The text separation above this line is correct \verb+topsep=10pt+.
    \item B The text separation below this line is correct \verb+topsep=10pt+.
  \end{enumerate}

\item The text separation above this line is correct%% \verb+topsep=10pt+.

  \begin{myminipage}{0.7\textwidth}
    \begin{enumerate}[left=0pt,topsep=10pt,itemsep=0pt]
      \item C The text separation above is correct?
      \item D The text separation below incorrect.
     \end{enumerate}
  \end{myminipage}\hfill
  \begin{myminipage}{0.2\textwidth}
    \par\addvspace{ 10pt } % or \vspace{10pt} here know the value off space
    \centering
    \fbox{Image here}
  \end{myminipage}
  %%\par\addvspace{20pt} % manual add topsep fix the problem but only if partopsep=0pt

\item E The text separation above incorrect% NOT equal to \verb+topsep=10pt+.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}



This is a really nice answer (which I don't fully understand). (Even if your choice menu doesn't satisfy the OP's preference for expl3. Even I could translate from this ....)

Thank you very much for the explanation and the solution \skip_vertical:N \c_zero_skip is what I needed.
